# How to I pass the database file name through one form to another

Tags: c#, winforms, global-variables, database-connection

In my windows application I am using MS access database. In mainForm (Contain menu), where user will select  (open) data file through Dialogbox. And he will be able to select a menu to access the other forms.

Here I need to store the datafile name in a variable and use the same datafile name in the connection string to get the data from the selected data file.

How can I pass the selected database file name through one form to another.

In form 1, I declare a variable;

```
public string dtFile;
```

I stored the file path in the `dtfile` variable at Open file Dialog.

`dtFile = openFileDialog.FileName;`

In the form2 I have written

`Form1 frm = new Form1;
string strDataFile = frm.dtFile;`

Here I am getting null value. How to get the data of dtFile variable of Form 1 in From 2

Comment: you can pass in the constructor of second form

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad. File name public variable is in Form1. I created a form1 object in Form2. Here I am not getting the data. it is showing `null`

Comment: see the answer hope it guides you to right way

Comment: In form1 I select the data file. and I am storing the data file in a public variable. I need to use the data file name throughout the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this, you will  be able to access all the things of Form1 on the other form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Form1 newform = new Form1();
            newform = this;
            this.Hide();
            MySecform = new Form2(ref newform);
            MySecform.Show();
    }
```

The other way around is using custom Events:

see details here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17371/Passing-Data-between-Windows-Forms

you can also make a **Static Class** if you want the value to be accessible in all forms of your application:

```
static class Global
{
    private static string _globalVar = "";

    public static string GlobalVar
    {
        get { return _globalVar; }
        set { _globalVar = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In First form declare `dtFileName` as static variable.

```
 public static string dtFileName;
```

On selecting file name through dialogbox

```
dtFileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
```

And in form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {        
        string strDataFilePath = "";

        public Form2 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            strDataFilePath = Form1.dtFileName.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Check this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/thiagu304/passdata05172006234318PM/passdata.aspx)